# Naming a function's output variable using function parameter in r

Tags: r, syntax

I'm trying to pre-generate some outcome sequences for a set of lottery problems and ideally I'd like to name the output sequence using a function parameter relating to the sequence number. Something like this:

```
seqgen <- function(x, a, b, p1, p2){
  sequence_x <- c()
  n = 1
  while (n<=5){
    internal <- sample(c(a, b), 20, replace = TRUE, prob = c(p1, p2))
    sequence_x <- c(sequence_x, internal)
    n <- n +1
  }
  return(sequence_x)
}
```

(where x would be the sequence number, a and b are the two possible outcomes which occur at probability p1 and p2 respectively.)

My main question is basically just if/how I could format it so that the "x" part of "sequence_x" is specified by the value of x in the function call? I will be generating 20 of these sequences for each problem, so ideally I'd also like to be able to increment x and add each iteration of the sequence for that problem to a vector list, but I'm sure I can figure that bit out once I've sorted the sequence naming part.

I have tried naming it as sequence_x, sequence.x, sequence(x), sequence"x", and various combinations thereof. I suspect there is a relatively simple method that I am just overlooking but I don't know the right keywords to search to figure it out.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I can’t tell exactly how you are calling this function or what the exact desired result is. This function will return a value. The variable names you use inside the function will not exist outside the function. You need to save the result when you call the function.

Comment: In addition to what @MrFlick suggests, you will almost certainly have a simpler workflow if you store your "sequence" of results in a `list` named `sequence`, indexed by `x`, rather than in several independent objects named `sequence_<x>` or similar.  For example, `sequence <- lapply(1:20, seqgen, a = "Heads", b = "Tails", p1 = 0.4, p2 = 0.6)` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will do my best to clarify though I'm not certain where the confusion is coming from so please let me know if I've misinterpreted! The function would be called in the standard way, by specifying parameters x, a, b, p1, and p2. The above code is just an example to illustrate the task core to the question, it's not part of a wider program so I'm not particularly concerned with how the output is saved etc. I just want to know if there is a way to use parameter x in the function call to name sequence x